# How to make analytics works in manifest 2.0

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I would like to know how to make it works because just paste the code in the app doesn't work.

The code generated by analytics is this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

- So, I tried to config this:

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://www.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'"

but it doesn't work because "content_security_polict" only accept HTTPS and not HTTP.

- I tried to config the path in "permission" too:

{
     ...
     "permissions":
          ["https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"]
     ...
}

but it doesn't workt too.

- I tried to set HTTPS fixed in the analytics code, but doesn't work too.

In a normal web page, it loads two files:

[image]

but in my app, it loads only one:

[image]

How can I make it works?

Comment: Please include your full current manifest.

Comment: @abraham This was the manifest I was using: https://github.com/Kunze/Pomodoro-app-chrome/commit/3b9d0e3c3ce898aa33a7244ad19ec99345625b1c#diff-4b1eb3dc48c4e16d49db5b42298fe654

Comment: @abraham In the commit I changed the code generated by analytics with another code(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/analytics/popup.js) and then my app works.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the library made specifically for Chrome apps and extensions.
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-platform-analytics